# Using COUNT to display 0 when using GROUP BY (sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table schema:

```
customers (customerID: integer, fName: string, lName: string)
orders (orderID: integer, itemID: integer, aID: integer, customerID: integer, date: date)
items (itemID: integer, description: string, price: integer)
```

SQL:

```
SELECT customers.customerID, COUNT(orders.customerID)
FROM customers INNER JOIN orders
    ON customers.customerID = orders.customerID
GROUP BY customers.customerID
```

How would I show the result of the number of orders each customer placed? When I use `GROUP BY` it removes the rows where `COUNT(orders.customerID)` is `NULL`. Is there a way to display a 0 instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `GROUP BY` that filters it out. It's the `INNER JOIN`.

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select customers.customerID,
    COUNT(orders.customerID)
from customers
left join orders on customers.customerID = orders.customerID
group by customers.customerID
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. I also did `left join` for `items` and I'm trying to find the average of the prices. When there isn't a purchase for that customer, it gives nothing rather than a 0. Do you know how I should approach that?

Comment: @stumped - What do you mean by "it gives nothing rather than a 0"? Do you get a null or no row at all?